# Grabbing a list of dates from a column and formatting them to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a program that will only apply to the rows whose dates match the current day. I know how to format the current date in MM/dd/yyyy but I'm having trouble looping through my list and formatting the dates to the list that I will use for comparing. Any advice helps, thank you!

```
function date() {
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "M/dd/yyyy")
  console.log(curDate)

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // get the sheet
  var columnF = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1); // get all the rows

  var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
  console.log('fvalues are; ', fValues)
  var format = []
  var datecolumn = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1)

  for (var i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
    var datecolumn = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    format.push(datecolumn)
  };
  console.log('date array is: ', format)

  var format2 = []
  for (var i = 0; i < fValues.length; i++) {

    var fmtcell = Utilities.formatDate(fValues, "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yyyy")

    format2.push(fmtcell)
  }
}
```

Comment: Read [mcve]. Provide a clear problem and not a goal/requirement for you to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to compare a group of dates, located in column `E` from `Sheet1`, with current date, as well as format these dates to a certain format.

If that's the case, you can do the following (check inline comments):

```js
function dateCompare() {
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // Retrieve list of dates in column E (formatted as current date):
  var firstRow = 2;
  var column = 5;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var dates = sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, numRows).getValues().map(function(date) {
    return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date[0]), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  });
  dates.forEach(function(date, i) { // Iterate through each date in column E
    if (date === curDate) { // Compare each date in column E to current date
      // Do something to the row:
      var row = sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    }
  });
}
```

Please consider that [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) returns a 2D dimensional array. You can transform this 2D into a one-dimensional array and format the dates in the array at the same time with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

#### Reference:

- [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatDate() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dt=new Date();
  var dtv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valufOf();
  var colfR=sh.getRange(2,5,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var colfV=colfR.getValues(); 
  var colfF=colfR.getNumberFormats();
  for (var i=0;i<colfV.length;i++) {
    var dtf=new Date(colfV[i][0]);
    var dtfv=new Date(dtf.getFullYear(),dtf.getMonth(),dtf.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(dtfv===dtv){colfF[i][0]="MM/dd/yyyy";}
  }
  colfR.setNumberFormats(colfF)
}
```